# IndexError: list index out of range while trying to read a text file

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, indexing, text

Im trying to make a word saver and reader from input (something like a dictionary)
My code:

```
if path.exists("data/inputs/" + word2 + ".txt"):
    file = open("data/inputs/" + word2 + ".txt", "r")

    for line in file:
        fields = line.split("; ")
        field1 = fields[0]
        answer=[field1]
        if fields[1]!="":
            field1 = fields[1]
            answer = [field1, field2]
```

Error:

```
    if fields[1]!="":
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I tried doing this with range, got error "must be an int or index",
Can you tell me how to work with these indexes and make it work please?

Comment: Obviously there is a line with only one field... check your input, and check for the length of `fields` before accessing an index.

Answer (score 0):

It means that at least one line of your file does not contain any "; ", so the result of `split('; ')` contains only one element... so calling `fields[1]` is an error!

If you want to test whether you have a second field in the line, you should replace `if fields[1] != ""` by `if len(fields) > 1`

Comment: It contains "; "

Comment: Well at least one line in the file does not! Maybe the last line of your file is an empty line?

Comment: or maybe, as suggested by @NomadMonad, you actually mean ';' with no space as a delimiter?

Comment: What do you mean by "line"? Theres only one line with one word, it should read the second word in that line, that does not exist, thats because the "if".

Comment: with `for line in file` you loop over all lines in the file. If you know that your file only contains one line, then this loop is useless. 
Second, the line `if fields[1]!=""` does not mean "if fields[1] does not exist", but "if fields[1] exists and is empty", which is different. In your case, `fields[1]` does not exist, hence the error

Comment: So you should probably replace `if fields[1]!=""` by `if len(fields) == 1`, which means that the result of the split returns a list with only one element